# How to use self design engine in SSL with Java language?

Tags: java, ssl

I am porting a ssl related project from c with openssl to java. In c part, we use openssl and set the engine as we designed ourselves. We use ENGINE_set_RSA() to set the rsa_priv_enc method which will use in the ssl handshake. Here is the problem, I want to find a class or method that can do the same thing in java, but nothing related was found. Maybe it is because English is not my local language and cannot use the exactly key word.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem sometime ago. Take a look to:

[Client connecting to an SSL server with Self-Signed Certificates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4463474/client-connecting-to-an-ssl-server-with-self-signed-certificates)

I think it will help you.